# Issue with zero and negative goal values

Tags: zero, turtle-graphics, ros

I’m following the example of http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals with navigation stack. If I set the goal position with positive values the turtle moves as expected, but If it's set to zero or negative values the turtle rotates in the same place, and It returns the message:

```
 “[ERROR] [1433622909.572352221]: Aborting because a valid plan could not be found. 
Even after executing all recovery behaviors.”
```

Does navigation only accepts positives values for the position MoveBaseGoal component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason might be that your map only has positive coordinates. So the robot obviously cant find a route as the goal is not on the map.

Maybe have a look at your map using rviz.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right, we've set max and minimum values to the global map and it's working fine now.

Comment: Alright. Could you please set the question to answered and or up vote?

Answer (score 0):

Turtlesim will always return positive values at the position because it has the (0,0) located at the bottom left corner, and by moving up and to the right it increases the coordinates values.
To allow navigation stack to handle the Turtlesim in a negative position (and relatively easy to do tests) I suggest modify the file turtleOdometry.cpp

It generates tf for odometry and some other stuff. What we have to do there is to change the callback function: poseCallback (..): msg-> msg- x> x by msg-> x - OFFSET_X and msg-> and -OFFSET_Y throughout the hole file. with OFSSET in positive calues, I put 5 to the offset and the turtle in the rviz appears almost in the world frame 1.1
With you will be able to test the navigation stack.

Then it is important to set the size and origin of global_costmap!
You need to modify the File: move_base.launch

```
<rosparam file = "$ (find <blah>) / global_costmap_params.yaml" command = "load" />

<Param name = "global_costmap / width" value = "20.0" />
<Param name = "global_costmap / height" value = "20.0" />
<Param name = "global_costmap / origin_x" value = "- 10.0" />
<Param name = "global_costmap / origin_y" value = "- 10.0" />
```

The default values ​​that are 10, 10, 0, 0 in that order.
For more info, read http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d
Regards,